# shared memory c++ cross platform

Tags: c++

I'm coding in C++ a program that works as a socket between other programs in different languages (C#, Python till now). This socket reads data from the USB-port, do some stuff and stream it to the other programs.

My Idea: each program asks over a port-massage to be part of the stream. As response this program gets a pointer to a shared memory.
Is this possible? shared memory over different programing-languages? and can I just pass the pointer to the shared memory to the other program? and is there a way to do it cross-platform (Unix and Windows)?

Comment: If the programs run on the same PC, you can consider pipes instead of shared memory. It's a more high level, and message oriented (so it seem more appropriate for broadcasting events/data).

Comment: @wohlstad I have to pass a lot of data from my program to a bunch of others in short time. I think pipes are not that fast compared to shared memory ... or?
If I'm wrong, tell me :)

Comment: Pipes are quite fast. At least on Windows it is using shared memory anyway (not sure about Linux etc.). Of course you'll need to profile it if performance is critical.

Comment: Added the pipe alternative as a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible?  shared memory over different programing-languages?

Yes.  Memory is memory, so a shared-memory region created by language A can be accessed by a program written in language B.

> and can I just passe the pointer to the shared memory to the other program?

It's not quite that simple; the other program won't be able to access the shared-memory region until it has mapped that same region into its own virtual-address space, using [shmat()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat) or [MapViewOfFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) or similar.

Note that the shared-memory region will likely be mapped to a different range of addresses in each process that is attached to it, so don't rely on the pointer to a piece of shared data in process A being the same as a pointer to that same data in process B.

> and is there a way to do it cross-platform ?

It looks like boost has an [API for shared memory](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html), if you want to go that route.  Alternatively, you could write your own [shared-memory API](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/system/SharedMemory.h), with different code inside the .cpp file for Windows and POSIX OS's, with appropriate `#ifdefs`.  That's [how I did](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/system/SharedMemory.cpp) it in my library, and it works okay.

Comment: _has mapped that same region_
Is not this a Limit for shared memory? Dose this not means I have to use the same tool to "mapped that same region" ? and I can not use "shamt" in every language... So I have also create a C Library to access the Storage?

Comment: You have to use some API call that knows how to access the OS’s shared memory facility… different languages may have different ways to do that, but they all end up calling to the OS’s API in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use shared memory, the answer above (by @JeremyFriesner) is a very good one.

However - as an alternaive to using shared memory, you can consider **named pipes**.
Some general information: [Named pipe - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe).

Named pipes API is more high-level than shared memory.
Instead of having a raw block of memory you need to manage yourself (including using some kind of interporocess locking mechanism like named mutex to access shared data), you get a transport layer for messages.

Performance-wise they are quite efficient. But of course you will have to profile it for your specific case.

The API is available for all languages that you mentioned (and many more):
For C# (on Windows): [How to: Use Named Pipes for Network Interprocess Communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication).
For C++:  on Windows: [Named Pipes - Win32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipes), and Linux: [Named pipes - Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html).
For Python: [Python named pipes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-mkfifo-method/).